# Скрипт, который считает, сколько дней осталось до дня рождения

Tags: php

Хорошо ли получилось?

```
<?php   
    $now = date('d.m.Y'); //сейчас
    $nowArr = explode('.', $now);

    $monthNow = date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $nowArr[1], $nowArr[0], $nowArr[2])); //текущий месяц

    $birthday = '23.03.1994'; //день рождение 
    $arr = explode('.', $birthday);

    $monthBirthday = date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $arr[1], $arr[0], $arr[2])); //месяй день рождения
    $rest = $monthBirthday - $arr[0]; //отсёк остальные дни, которые идут после моего дня рождения в этом месяце.

    $days = 0;

    for($i = $nowArr[1]; $i <= 12; $i++) {
        $days = $days + date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, $nowArr[0], $nowArr[2])); // количество дней до конца года сначала месяца
        if($i == $arr[1]) break;

        if($i == 12) {
            for($j = 1; $j <= $arr[1]; $j++) {
                $days = $days + date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $j, $nowArr[0], $nowArr[2])); // количество дней до конца нужного месяца сначала месяца
            }
        }
    }

    echo $days - $nowArr[0] - $rest - 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

Думаю можно чуть чуть упростить:

```
$birthday = '23.03.1994'; //день рождение
$arr = explode('.', $birthday);
$tm=mktime(0, 0, 0, $arr[1], $arr[0], date('Y'));
if($tm<time()) $tm=mktime(0, 0, 0, $arr[1], $arr[0], date('Y')+1);
echo intval( ($tm-time())/86400 );
```

Ну еще добавить проверку, что день рождения сегодня. (ваш вариант в этом случае выдает -1 день)

Answer (score 2):

Куда так сложно? рассчёты можно уложить в <s>*2*</s> **3** строчки.

```
$birthday = '23.03.1994';

$bd = explode('.', $birthday);
$bd = mktime(0, 0, 0, $bd[1], $bd[0], date('Y') + ($bd[1].$bd[0] <= date('md')));
$days_until = ceil(($bd - time()) / 86400);

echo $days_until;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $birthday = '23.03.1994';

    $cd = new \DateTime('today'); // Сегодня, время 00:00:00
    $bd = new \DateTime($birthday); // Объект Дата дня рождения
    $bd->setDate($cd->format('Y'), $bd->format('m'), $bd->format('d')); // Устанавливаем текущий год, оставляем месяц и день
    $tmp = $cd->diff($bd); // Разница дат
    if($tmp->invert){ // Если в этом году уже был (разница "отрицательная")
        $bd->modify('+1 year'); // Добавляем год
        $tmp = $cd->diff($bd); // Снова вычисляем разницу
    }
    echo $tmp->days; // Результат в днях
```

Остаётся только изучить "**проблему 29 февраля**"

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = '12.04.1983'; //дата рождения
$a = explode('.',$date); //режем на массив
$b = mktime(0,0,0,$a[1],$a[0],date('Y'));
$c = strtotime(date('d.m.Y'));
if ($b<$c){ //проверяем было ли д.р. в этом году
    echo (($c-mktime(0,0,0,$a[1],$a[0],date('Y')-1))/86400);
}
else echo (($c-$b)/86400)*-1;
```